# how to retain dynamic dropdown values after page refresh using spring and jsp

Tags: spring, jsp

I am having 3 dropdowns.customername and companyname and servername.like this..

[image]

Based on Customer drop down i am populating Company Names.and based on Company names dropdown i am population server names using Spring and javascript.

If i click go button my page is refreshing.That time my droddown values are not retaining..

Can you any one suggest me regarding to this.

This is my code:

on click of customer dropdown i am calling onchange method in jsp.

```
<td valign="bottom">
     <form:select path="CustomerId" id="customerDetails">
     <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Customer</option>
     <form:options items="${map.customerList}"
     itemLabel="customerName" itemValue="customerId" />
    </form:select> <br>
</td>
```

with this i am getting my customer dropdown values.Onchange of the customer i am getting company names..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#customerDetails").change(function() {
            var value1 = $('#customerDetails :selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'companynames',
                data : {
                    selectedcustomername : value1
                },
                success : function(result) {
                    getcompNames(result);
               }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller's code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/companynames", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody String getEnvironmentNames(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam String selectedcustomername) throws SQLException {
     request.setAttribute("selectedcustomername", selectedcustomername);
     System.out.println("selectedcustomername"+selectedcustomername);
     ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
     modelAndView.addObject("environments", new Environments());
     List<Environments>  environmentnamesList= loginDelegate.getEnvironments(selectedcustomername);
     Collections.sort(environmentnamesList, new CustomComparator());
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     System.out.println("gson"+gson);
     String jsonString = gson.toJson(environmentnamesList);
     System.out.println("jsonString"+jsonString);
     return jsonString;
}
```

Processing response of controller:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function getcompNames(result){
    $('#environmentName').empty().append('<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select An Environment</option>');
    var data = JSON.parse(result);
    $.each(data, function(key, value)
    {
        $("#environmentName").append("<option>" + value.environments_name +" - "+ value.environments_purpose + "</option>");

    });

}
```

This is my company ui code.

```
<td width="20%" nowrap="nowrap" class="boldFontSize3">
   <b>Company:</b>
   <select class="body" name="environmentName" id="environmentName" class="body">
      <option selected="selected">Select a comapany name</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

Like this way only i am getting servername.

Go button code:

```
<input name="Submit" value="Go" type="submit" class="boldFontSize3" />
```

after clicking go button my dropdown values are null

..my problem is when user click on go button my page is refreshing.i am getting customer dropdown values from modelandview object.For that i am getting customer dropdown values.But after page refresh i am not getting companynames and server.Because restcall will happen only onchange of customer Dropdown only.

Comment: You can send go button request with ajax without refresh page.

Comment: Try change `var value1 = $('#customerDetails :selected').text();` to `var value1 = $('#customerDetails').find('option:selected').text();`

Comment: both are same..i am getting selected customer name in both cases.